# Can we use discord.py to run a slash command found in a server?

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to figure out a way to get a script to run a slash command specifically found in the server. Is there a way we can do this without issues using the discord API?

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried simply entering the command contents instead of `'command'`? E.g:
```await channel1.send("/help")```

Comment: Googling your title led me to this: https://github.com/interactions-py/library

Maybe you can look at their source code or use their package.